# Blending jumbotron into background image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

so I'm trying to get my jumbotron blend in with a background image. I want just the text to be visible, and not the white background of the jumbortron itself. I tried using background:none; and background-color: transparent; but to no avail. Can anyone help?

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url("../images/home-office.jpg");

  height: 100%;    

  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.jumbotron {
    background: none;
}
```

```html
<!--********TOP JUMBOTRON********-->

    <header class="jumbotron bg" id="landing-view">
            <div class="container top">
                <h1 class='name'>Conor Humphreys</h1>
                <p class='title'>Full-Stack Software Developer</p>
            </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting `background` of your div when you set `.jumbotron {background: none}`
You Should move the `.jumbotron {background: none}` above the `.bg` selector in CSS.

Comment: Thanks, but still nothing

Comment: Then, Somethings else must be interfering with the background or your image path may be wrong!

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, this is an appropriate way to address this:

I changed the code as suggested by @damnitrahul (see the snippet) and it works as he indicated it would. Since the image is unreachable from this snippet, I added a red background color instead.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.jumbotron {
    background: none;
}

.bg {
  background-image: url("../images/home-office.jpg");

  height: 100%;    

  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!--********TOP JUMBOTRON********-->

    <header class="jumbotron bg" id="landing-view">
            <div class="container top">
                <h1 class='name'>Conor Humphreys</h1>
                <p class='title'>Full-Stack Software Developer</p>
            </div>
    </header>
```

To test this, edit this snippet and in your css move `.bg` above `.jumbotron` like you had it and you will see the red background disappear.

> I believe you did not see the result when you followed @damn's advice because your image path or filename is incorrect.

Please apply any upvotes to @damnitrahul's answer.

Comment: Hey, I really appreciate you explaining it in a better way. Cheers!

Comment: It's still not working for me. Is there a way that I can post a screenshot?

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) page to see how to add an image. You'll want to edit your question and follow the instructions in the link.